# min and max in Rcpp programs

Tags: r, rcpp

I was converting an R  function into Rcpp function. It is all fine but I have difficulties in using the standard max and min function. The code below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

double f4RandomC(double x, double a, double b) {
  double out, temp;

  temp=(log( (a*(1-x)) / (a+x) )) /log(b) ;
  out= std::min(1,temp );
  return out;
}
```

returns me error "no matchinf function for call min(int, &double). If possible, I would lioke to use the std:: library min function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just change `std::min(1,temp)` to `std::min(1.0,temp)`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double f4RandomC(double x, double a, double b) {
  double out, temp;

  temp =(log( (a*(1-x)) / (a+x) )) /log(b) ;
  out = std::min(1.0,temp );
  return out;
}
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the template definition of `std::min`

```
template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b);
```

which is defined in terms of only one type (`T`), whereas you were passing it two data types (`int` and `double`).

Or since you are only comparing two values, you could do this a little more concisely by replacing `std::min` with the ternary operator (`?:`):

```
double f4RandomC(double x, double a, double b) {
  double temp;

  temp =(log( (a*(1-x)) / (a+x) )) /log(b) ;
  return temp < 1 ? temp : 1;
}
```

I'm guessing the type deduction is a little more flexible for `operator<` than `std::min`.

Two other options with `std::min`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double f4RandomC2(double x, double a, double b) {
  double out, temp;
  int z = 1;
  temp =(log( (a*(1-x)) / (a+x) )) /log(b) ;
  out = std::min( static_cast<double>(z),temp );
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double f4RandomC3(double x, double a, double b) {
  double out, temp;
  int z = 1;
  temp =(log( (a*(1-x)) / (a+x) )) /log(b) ;
  out = std::min<double>( z,temp );
  return out;
}
```

Although in this case it's certainly much easier to just change `1` to `1.0` than to (unnecessarily) define `int z` just to cast it to a double anyways later on.

You can learn a lot by reading through function / class definitions (as with most programming languages) - [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) are pretty standard sources - and it will often make compiler errors seem much less cryptic.